# Added user to firebase, is unable to see/edit DB

Tags: firebase, permission-denied, firebase-console

I have created a simple db structure Firebase. And I added a user to it with a google account.

But when I login to google with that account and go to: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[project-name]/database/data

I get the message:"There was an error completing your request".
When i look in the network tab of the chrome inspector I see:

> 403
>   "Check Policy: User does not have permission to execute the specified operation."

Of course I checked [Firebase's status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/). And all is running normal.

Is there somebody that has a clue what could be the case?

Comment: How did you add the user?

Comment: Just by going to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[project-name]/authentication/users and clicking on add user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a user in the [Auth panel of the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/-/authentication/users) that is a user meant for use in your apps. These users (thankfully) don't have access to the Firebase console of your project.

To grant a **collaborator** access to your Firebase console, add them from the settings menu:

1. Click the Settings icon next to the <kbd>Overview</kbd> menu
   [image: Adding collaborators from the Firebase console]
2. Click <kbd>Users and permissions</kbd> to open the Cloud <kbd>IAM & Admin</kbd> console.
3. Click <kbd>Add</kbd> at the top of the list to show a popup.
   [image: Adding collaborators from the Cloud console]
4. Type the email address of the user in the <kbd>Members</kbd> box.
5. Select a role in the <kbd>Roles</kbd> dropdown. I usually pick <kbd>Project > Owner</kbd>, <kbd>Project > Editor</kbd>, or <kbd>Project > Viewer</kbd>.
6. Click <kbd>Add</kbd> at the bottom of the popup.